# win32com.client.Dispatch(“Outlook.Application”) error pywintypes.com_error((-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32

A lot of folks have reported seeing this error but the solution being suggested has not worked or is not pertinent enough.

I have a server where Outlook 2013 is not installed and being a production server it will not be installed. Now I have seen people suggesting using the MakePy.py utility but that hasn't worked. I have asked our Exchange support folks to install the Object Library and they are skeptical at best and they tell me it is not as straightforward as that.

How can I make this work with minimal effort?

Answer (score 0):

If Outlook is not installed, attempting to create an instance of the Outlook.Application object will obviously fail. How can it possibly work?

Comment: But few have stated that with MakePy.py you can get all the Outlook functionality with installing Outlook client. I have tried that but that does nothing.  What purpose does it server if Outlook has to be installed in the first place? What about the Outlook 15 Object Library?

Comment: Think about - you want all the functionality of Outlook without ever installing it. Why would anybody ever pay for Outlook if they can get some Python script that does it all?

Comment: try: "[Where to acquire the CDO Libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/171440)" then "[Microsoft Exchange Server MAPI Client and Collaboration Data Objects 1.2.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1004)"

Answer (score 0):

try: "[Where to acquire the CDO Libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/171440)" then "[Microsoft Exchange Server MAPI Client and Collaboration Data Objects 1.2.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1004)"

"This web release follows the Microsoft Lifecycle policy of Exchange Server 2003, which is in Extended Support since April 2009. It is recommended that new Exchange development leverage Exchange Web Services, the Outlook Object Model, or the Outlook MAPI Client Library."